# proof of lemma for relative extreme theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let  $\ g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_k $ be $C^1$ functions in an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ and
$$
M=\{x \in U \mid g_1(x)=0,g_2(x)=0,\ldots,g_k(x)=0 \}.
$$
If $a \in M$ and the forms $g'_1(a)...g'_k(a)$ are linearly independent, prove that for every vector $v \in TM_a=\{grad(g_1(a)),\ldots,grad(g_k(a))\}^{\perp}$ there is path $\phi : (-r,r) \to M$ such that $\phi(0)=a$ and $\phi'(0)=v$.

My professor used this lemma to prove relative extreme theorem, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: What is the relative extreme theorem?  The extreme value theorem (a function on a compact set attains a max and min)? From the notation and tags, I can't tell if the question is about the constraint qualification for the Lagrangian, or if this is an issue about whether a particular vector field is conservative so that a scalar potential $\phi$ exists that integrates the field.

Comment: relative extreme theoreme is lagrange multiplier theorem